# Template class does not name a type error, separated definition and declaration for header

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I am attempting to create a templated vector class, but upon compilation I am receiving an error of

```
def.hpp:3:1: error: 'TempVector' does not name a type
```

I keep referring to reference material and my syntax and handling of the header file declaration and definition (.h and .hpp) seem right to me, but I can not figure out what I am overlooking.

Below is the three files I am working with, thank you.

driver.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "dec.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
  TempVector <int> v1;
  cout<<"ran successfully"<<endl;
}
```

dec.h:

```
#ifndef DEC_H
#define DEC_H
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

// Declaration of class Vector

template <typename T>
class TempVector {

public:
   TempVector ();

private:
   T* array;
   static const unsigned int spare = 10;
};

#include "def.hpp"
#endif
```

def.hpp:

```
template <typename T>
  TempVector<T>::TempVector () {
  std::cout<<"ran successfully";
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious after a quick glance - how are you compiling these files?

Comment: Looks like `def.hpp` file is compiled as a separate translation unit, which would suggest an issue with project configuration or compilation process.

Comment: I am using the command ```g++ -o run driver.cpp dec.h def.hpp```, I have also tried using g++6 and rearranging the order of the files on the command line.

Comment: Never include header files in your compilation command.  You should just need `g++ -o run driver.cpp`.  `include` will make sure the header files are imported into `driver.cpp`